# Grid Column in Sharepoint List

Tags: wss-3.0

I need to create a grid column type for sales team of my company:

Please have a look at following image.

[image]

Grid column type example - this column type is just making single choices on each row - I need something which can allow various types of columns inside the grid more like a table. So that I can have columns like Qty(number), Cost(number), From Dept(drop-down), To Dept (drop-down) as column heads against the products - so all info of the products can be inside a single column (instead of multiple items in a list) and yet the info is linked row-wise i.e. qty in first row belongs to product 1 - they are linked for the purpose of filtering records later on.

By the way, the responses of this form are saved in a spreadsheet like any normal google form - will email the link to this spread sheet as well.

Is this possible?

Aprreciate all help!.

-saumil

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Survey template which is setup in a similar way.  If that does not meet your needs you can always setup a custom field definition.  Any SharePoint list can be exported to a spreadsheet and an email can be generated with a simple workflow or alert.